# Magento 2.4.1 display banner on product listing page

Tags: php, magento2

I'm trying to display some banners on overridden product listing page in magento 2.4.1.
The banner is displayed in the same size as a regular product, in its place(
[page example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7b5W.png) )

I have my custom banner collection.
banner collection:

- id
- content
- position

Banner collection has sorting by position.

My list.phtml:

```
<?php
$_productCollection = $block->getLoadedProductCollection();
$categoryId = $this->getLayer()->getCurrentCategory()->getId();
$_banners = $helper->getBanner($categoryId);
$banner_count = $_banners->getSize();
$banners = $_banners->getData();
$_page_limit = $block->getToolbarBlock()->getLimit();
?>
<?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
    <?php $repeat = true; ?>
    <?php while ($repeat): ?>
        <?php if (
            isset($banners[$banners_iterator]) &&
            $banners[$banners_iterator]['position'] == $current_position &&
            $current_position < $_page_limit
        ): ?>
            <--- display banner with current position --->
            <?php $banners_iterator++; ?>
            <?php $current_position++; ?>
        <?php else: ?>
            <li class="item product product-item">
                <---display products--->
            </li>
            <?php $current_position++; ?>
            <?php $repeat = false; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php $repeat = true; ?>
<?php while ($repeat): ?>
    <?php if (
        $banner_count > $banners_iterator &&
        isset($banners[$banners_iterator]) &&
        $current_position <= $_page_limit
    ): ?>
        <--- display banners if they locate after all products --->
       <?php $repeat = true; ?>
        <?php $banners_iterator++; ?>
        <?php $current_position++; ?>
    <?php else: ?>
        <?php $repeat = false; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

I select data from the collection, and it's working well. But I need work with collection and  its methods (->getContent, ->getPosition etc.). And I shouldn't use a foreach loop inside a loop, because it can slow down page opening.

edited:
I want to display these banners between products using a collection, not an array, and not use two foreach loops. the first for products is the default, and the second for my banners. For example how not to work :

```
 foreach($product_collection as product){ 
foreach($banner_collection as banner){ } 
}
```

I will be grateful for any ideas.

Comment: Try to form a specific question. You want to accomplish a loop behaviour but do not want to use a foreach loop?

Comment: @nonNumericalFloat, 
I want to display these banners between products using a collection, not an array, and not use two foreach loops. the first for products is the default, and the second for my banners. Аor example how not to work :
foreach($product_collection as product){
    foreach($banner_collection as banner){
}
}